# what is difference between null and "null" of String.valueOf(String Object)

Tags: java, string, object, if-statement, null

in my project ,Somewhere I have to use if n else condition to check the null variables

```
String stringValue = null;
String valueOf = String.valueOf(stringValue);
```

but when i check the condition like

```
  if (valueOf == null) {
        System.out.println("in if");
    } else {
        System.out.println("in else");
    }
```

then output is **"in else"** ,why this is happening?

Comment: null reference is different from "null" String. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)

Comment: a debugger would have helped?

Comment: netbeans dont have debugger for java-string manupulation

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's the **source code** of `String.valueOf`: -

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

As you can see, for a `null` value it returns `"null"` string.

So,

```
String stringValue = null;
String valueOf = String.valueOf(stringValue);
```

gives `"null"` string to the `valueOf`.

Similarly, if you do: -

```
System.out.println(null + "Rohit");
```

You will get: -

```
"nullRohit"
```

---

**EDIT**

Another Example:

```
Integer nulInteger = null;
String valueOf = String.valueOf(nulInteger) // "null"
```

But in this case.

```
Integer integer = 10;
String valueOf = String.valueOf(integer) // "10"
```

Comment: thanks but when we compare both null and "null" then why both are not equal.

Comment: @arvin_codeHunk, `null` is an empty object, whereas `"null"` is an actual string containing the characters 'n', 'u', 'l', and 'l'.

Comment: The String here is written as null telling you that you just took the String value of null which is equal to `"null"`. So a `null` will not be equal to `"null"` literal.

Comment: @rohit jain ok,but "As you can see, for a null value it returns "null" string" from above answer,if this null returns "null" string then off course this null and "null" both should be equal,correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @arvin_codeHunk.. Actually was searching for a valuable source for you. Well, the conversion of `null` to `"null"` string does not happens always, but only in certain pre-defined cases. Like in case of `String Concatenation` - As defined in [JLS - String Concatenation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1). However, it is not defined for `String Comparison`.

Comment: @arvin_codeHunk.. Also see [JLS - String Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can have a look at the implementation of the method: valueOf(). You will know what happened then.

In JDK 1.5, its code is like this:

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

From the code, you can see that if the object is null it will return a not null string with "null" value in it, which means the valueOf object is not null.